# NSTableView without NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsscrollview

I'm thinking to make un-scrollable nstableview.

Is it possible to have a table view without scroll view, or maybe to extract table view from scroll view ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is good practice (I'm googling about that - that's how I found your question)(**Edit:** why wouldn't it be?), but it is possible to get an NSTableView without the NSScrollView: drag out a 'custom view' and set it's identity to `NSTableView`. There you are! The only thing is you don't get any visual feedback from IB about the tableview. But you can still set outlets (the delegate, datasource etc) in IB. I am afraid you'll have to set UI options (things like 'draws background' and such) from code (at least they don't appear if you use my 'trick').

You could even do it without IB (I found this code on SO, I didn't test it):

```
MyDataSource *dataSource = [[MyDataSource alloc] init];
NSTableColumn *column = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"onlyColumn"];
NSTableView *table = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame: frameWhereTableViewShouldGo];
[table setDataSource:dataSource];
[table addTableColumn:column];
[theViewYouWantATableViewIn addSubview:table];
```

Comment: I haven't tried this with an NSTableView, but I have with an NSScrollView, and it just doesn't work correctly because the view keeps changing its own size.. you would have to subclass NSTableView and override `-setFrame:` and perhaps others...

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't something else? You can initialise every view in the Cocoa library from code. IB does this too, behind the scenes. @GradyPlayer

Comment: oops i misspoke i meant with NSOutlineView which is a subclass of NSTableView. I have tried to remove that from the scroll view, but it was funky

Answer (score 0):

At least you can implement your NSScrollView-subclass and reimplement its `scrollWheel:` method.

```
@interface MyScrollView : NSScrollView

@property (nonatomic) BOOL scrollingEnabled;

@end

@implementation

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event
{
  if (self.scrollingEnabled)
    [super scrollWheel:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -4):

Did you mean this?

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;
```

Comment: pardon me, your answer is in iOS, but I was asked how to do it in  mac-osx app. because there's no `scrollEnabled` in mac-osx API